# angular.js show parsed value after blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive which applys to input fields where the user should be able to enter a time in several possible formats and then the directive should parse the user input to a correct time format

e.g. The user insert 1234 into the input field and the value should be parsed to 12:34

The value is parsed correctly but when the input loses the focus the value in the input field stays 1234 instead of changing to 12:34.

How can I force the input so that it show the parsed value?

I create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/t68ajjnv/1/

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.theTime = "00:00";
});

app.directive("myTime", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                if (value.length === 4) {
                    return value.substr(0,2) + ":" + value.substr(2,2);
                }
                if (value.length === 3) {
                    return "0" + value.substr(0,1) + ":" + value.substr(1,2);
                }
                if (value.length === 2) {
                    return value + ":00";
                }
                if (value.length === 1) {
                    return "0" + value + ":00";
                }
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It's just a simple example implementation for the parser so just ignore the code there.

Comment: did you try to use $setViewValue and then ngModel.$render(); instead (instead of $parsers I mean)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional logic to your parser function to update the element when it parses it.

```
angular.element(element).val(value);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/t68ajjnv/8/.

This will only update on the blur event since otherwise the change to the input would cause the cursor to move to the end of the input after each character was typed.